# What is the easiest way to grab this string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to grab a substring from a string

So I need "Type is required after FD analyst has been assigned. User is not authorized."

out of this:

at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at DOCSIDE.Web.Util.ExecuteMethod(Object o, String method, Object[] arguments, String buildNumber) in C:\Software\DOCSIDEFINAL\DOCSIDE\Main\DOCSIDEBusinessLogic\Web\Util.cs:line 247

+++ DOCSIDE Sproc - updateTrkRecord Line - 2203 [@@Error=50000] Type is required after FD analyst has been assigned. User is not authorized.
   at DOCSIDE.Web.WebMethods.UpdateTrkRecord(TrkRecordCUD t, TrkRecordAction a) in C:\Software\DOCSIDEFINAL\DOCSIDE\Main\Web.cs:line 255

Comment: Where does that come from?  Can you show us the code you have so far so we can help?  This isn't a code writing service so help us to help you :)

Comment: You can use a combination of substring and indexOf. However, thing to consider would be that wether you are going to get same type of string always. Guess you'll have to elaborate the problem statement a bit more here!

Answer (score 0):

if your error message is always the same you can use indexOf and substring

**example code**

```
<script>
    function test() {
        var str = 'at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters) at DOCSIDE.Web.Util.ExecuteMethod(Object o, String method, Object[] arguments, String buildNumber) in C:\Software\DOCSIDEFINAL\DOCSIDE\Main\DOCSIDEBusinessLogic\Web\Util.cs:line 247+++ DOCSIDE Sproc - updateTrkRecord Line - 2203 [@@Error=50000] Type is required after FD analyst has been assigned. User is not authorized. at DOCSIDE.Web.WebMethods.UpdateTrkRecord(TrkRecordCUD t, TrkRecordAction a) in C:\Software\DOCSIDEFINAL\DOCSIDE\Main\Web.cs:line 255';
        var start = str.indexOf("[@@Error=50000]");
        var end = str.indexOf(" at DOCSIDE.Web.WebMethods");
        var get = str.substring(start + 16, end);
        document.write(get);
    }
</script>
```

**version 2**

if you know error 50000 is always the same

```
<script>
    function test() {
        var str = 'at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters) at DOCSIDE.Web.Util.ExecuteMethod(Object o, String method, Object[] arguments, String buildNumber) in C:\Software\DOCSIDEFINAL\DOCSIDE\Main\DOCSIDEBusinessLogic\Web\Util.cs:line 247+++ DOCSIDE Sproc - updateTrkRecord Line - 2203 [@@Error=50000] Type is required after FD analyst has been assigned. User is not authorized. at DOCSIDE.Web.WebMethods.UpdateTrkRecord(TrkRecordCUD t, TrkRecordAction a) in C:\Software\DOCSIDEFINAL\DOCSIDE\Main\Web.cs:line 255';
            //Check if error is 50000
            if( str.indexOf('Error=50000') >= 0){
                var start = str.indexOf("[@@Error=50000]");
                var end = str.indexOf(" at DOCSIDE.Web.WebMethods");
                var get = str.substring(start + 16, end);
                document.write(get);
            }        
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple: care this is with ES6 syntax

```js
let str=`
at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters) at DOCSIDE.Web.Util.ExecuteMethod(Object o, String method, Object[] arguments, String buildNumber) in C:\Software\DOCSIDEFINAL\DOCSIDE\Main\DOCSIDEBusinessLogic\Web\Util.cs:line 247

+++ DOCSIDE Sproc - updateTrkRecord Line - 2203 [@@Error=50000] Type is required after FD analyst has been assigned. User is not authorized. at DOCSIDE.Web.WebMethods.UpdateTrkRecord(TrkRecordCUD t, TrkRecordAction a) in C:\Software\DOCSIDEFINAL\DOCSIDE\Main\Web.cs:line 255`;

console.log(str.includes("Type is required after FD analyst has been assigned. User is not authorized."));
```